# VS Not Prints To The Output Window

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I would like to print and see the message in the "Output Window" in Visual Studio 2013. After running this C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){ 
    cout << "hello world";
}
```

I cannot see the message in the output window. Instead, a black window in which the message "hello world" is written seems instantly and closes.

I disabled "Redirect all output text to the Immediate window". However, it is still not printing the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is expected, because the program is completing its functions. You can change the code to this:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "hello world";
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Which will make the window pause until you hit a key to continue, but after printing hello world the program is finished running and will close.